# Splint barfs on __thread, which is part of C99

Tags: c, linux, gcc, splint, thread-local-storage

Running splint

```
matt@stanley:~/cpfs$ splint -paramuse +gnuextensions cpfs.c
```

Halts on this line:

```
__thread int cpfs_errno;
```

With a parse error:

```
cpfs.c:127:13: Parse Error: Non-function declaration: __thread :
               int. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help parseerrors.)
*** Cannot continue.
```

Checking the documentation and gargle comes up with no mention of `__thread`. However [`__thread` is part of the C99 spec](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C99-Thread_002dLocal-Edits.html#C99-Thread_002dLocal-Edits), which Splint allegedly supports (insert reference).

What's going on here? How can I get splint to recognize `__thread`?

Comment: I was not aware that splint supported C99 now. When did that happen?

Comment: Sometime in 2002: http://lclint.cs.virginia.edu/release.html, "supports most": http://lclint.cs.virginia.edu/faq.html

Comment: I swear I checked their website not six months ago, and it said it doesn't support C99 constructs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [splint FAQ](http://www.splint.org/faq.html#quest14), just add `-D__thread=` to the splint command line. This will have the effect of removing the `__thread` keyword from the code while splint is examining it. I'm assuming here that splint is not particularly thread aware, and wouldn't be able to use the information that was conveyed to GCC by the keyword.

Answer (score 6):

`__thread` is not in C99.  It is a GNU C extension - the section you have linked to is within [Extensions to the C Language Family](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions).  It describes the extension in terms of changes to the C99 standard, presumably as preparation to have it adopted in a future revision of the standard.

Comment: I am not sure that "__thread" isn't part of c99.  Other comments here say that it is.  Frustratingly, the only evidence I have seen comes from gcc documents: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/C99-Thread_002dLocal-Edits.html  -- can anyone check with the real standard.

Comment: @Adrian Ratnapala: Neither the word `thread` nor `__thread` appear anywhere in the C99 standard.  You can [download a copy of N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), which is a committee working draft consisting only of the final C99 text with TC1, TC2 and TC3 applied.